¿Cómo puedo ocultar la barra de tareas en Windows 11 solo si hay una ventana maximizada?
Quiero hacer que la barra de tareas de Windows 11 se oculte solamente cuando tengo una ventana maximizada, caso contrario, se muestre la barra de tareas, he visto esto en linux y me gusta mucho así, entiendo que Windows 11 no tiene una opción nativa para esta funcionalidad específica pero estoy intentando hacerlo con AutoHotkey.
Aquí está el script que estoy intentando utilizar, sin embargo, funciona mal porque si oculta la barra de tareas, pero se sigue viendo el espacio vacío que esta suele ocupar.
Quisiera saber que estoy haciendo mal y como puedo arreglar este problema
#Persistent
SetTimer, CheckMaximized, 500
Return

CheckMaximized:
    ; Obtiene el estado de la ventana activa
    WinGet, state, MinMax, A
    MouseGetPos, , y   ; Obtiene la posición Y del cursor
    bottomRange := A_ScreenHeight - 10 ; Definir un rango de 10 píxeles desde la parte inferior de la pantalla
    if (y >= bottomRange or state != 1) ; Si el cursor está en el rango inferior o no hay una ventana maximizada
    {
        ShowTaskbar()
    }
    else
    {
        HideTaskbar()
    }
Return

HideTaskbar()
{
    ; Oculta la barra de tareas
    WinHide, ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
    WinHide, ahk_class Shell_SecondaryTrayWnd
    ; Oculta el botón de inicio
    Control, Hide,, Start, ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
    ; Oculta el ícono de la bandeja del sistema
    Control, Hide,, ReBarWindow32, ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
}

ShowTaskbar()
{
    ; Muestra la barra de tareas
    WinShow, ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
    WinShow, ahk_class Shell_SecondaryTrayWnd
    ; Muestra el botón de inicio
    Control, Show,, Start, ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
    ; Muestra el ícono de la bandeja del sistema
    Control, Show,, ReBarWindow32, ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
}

Explicación del Script

CheckMaximized: Esta función comprueba cada 500 milisegundos si la ventana activa está maximizada. También si el cursor está en los últimos diez pixeles inferiores de la pantalla, siendo el caso se mostrará la barra de tareas

HideTaskbar: Oculta la barra de tareas

ShowTaskbar: Muestra la barra de tareas


Yo supongo que estoy haciendo mal las funciones ShowTaskbar() y HideTaskbar(), pero no sé mucho de programación para entender mi problema, les agradezco mucho su ayuda

Prueba con el código de SKAN. https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/17678-script-to-fullscreen-any-app/
